# How to set timeout for grpc streaming responses (C++)

Tags: c++, grpc

I noticed grpc supports deadline setting.

```
auto deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(timeout_sec);
context->set_deadline(deadline);
```

But for the following code

```
// context_ and stream_ has already been created beforehand.
UpdateClientDeadline(context_.get(), timeout_sec);
stream_->Read(response);
```

Deadline doesn't work here (I checked by sleeping indefinitely long time at server-side).

I know re-creating stream works. But to keep high performance, that doesn't seem to be a solution to me.

Wondering what's the standard way to implement that in C++ grpc?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlines don't exist in gRPC per-send/receive operation, only per-stream (start to finish).  If you need to enforce a deadline per message, you'll need to keep track of that on your own end and cancel the RPC if the deadline is met.

Comment: That's my guess :(

Comment: That's not a guess; I work on the project.  :)

The issue is that there is nothing in gRPC per-message to let the sender know the other side has received the message.  That would need to go into your own streaming protocol as some kind of an ack.

Comment: Hmm, from this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/grpc-gains-advanced-traffic-management-features), it mentions new support for "maximum stream duration (timeout)".

Comment: Stream timeouts are not new.  They have been around literally forever.  However, you need to set them on the stream when it is created.  You cannot change deadlines after stream creation, or set one per-send/receive operation.  For directions on setting the stream's timeout, there's this blog post: https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/ or this guide: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/deadlines/